# EU region not available when connecting SES using boto

Tags: python, boto

I am trying to connect to EU region for SES using boto. But it is not showing the EU region in the region list.

```
boto.ses.regions()
[RegionInfo:us-east-1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SES in EU region is very new](https://sesblog.amazon.com/post/Tx3PU3POPUV0CC8/Announcing-SES-Endpoint-in-Europe), so it takes a bit till boto is adjusted.
In the meantime, you could create the connection yourself:

```
import boto.ses
from boto.regioninfo import RegionInfo
region = RegionInfo(None, "eu-west-1", "email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com")
conn = boto.ses.SESConnection(region=region,aws_access_key_id='<key_id>', aws_secret_access_key='<secret_key>')
```